# Editing an answer created a new one

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, inline-editor

I was editing my answer here: [issue with form method get on next page, would like for people to not see the initial page unless they hit the submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765135/561731)

And when I clicked submit somehow it created a [**new** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765135/issue-with-form-method-get-on-next-page-would-like-for-people-to-not-see-the-ini/6765232#6765232), which I have since deleted, but you can see if you have eough rep.

Why did this happen?  I think it has something to do with the inline edits.

I have since flagged the deleted answer for moderator attention.

Comment: We had a similar issue raised over on [meta.SU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2908/) semi-recently. No one, the OP included, could repro there either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me too.

After submitting the edit, you can press backspace of hit the back button, and come back to the edit screen. Edit some more and post that, and you have another answer.

Just delete the one you don't want and everything would be ok.

Comment: there is no `edit screen` of inline editing. once you hit back you leave the question....

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this; can you?

Comment: I have not since repro'd this issue.... I will let you know if it happens again.